# React- how to pass a state from one component to another

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to pass the value of "value" from AdminNavBar.js to Sentiment.js and replace the value in **ticker** variable. I am really new to React. it will be fine for any better approach as well.

What I actually need is, Search for a ticket and that state will be passed on to Sentiment.js and it will replace the ticker.

Thanks a lot in advance

**AdminNavBar.js**

```
import React from "react";

class AdminNavbar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    console.log('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Navbar className="navbar-top navbar-dark" expand="md" id="navbar-main">
          <Container fluid>
            <Link
              className="h4 mb-0 text-white text-uppercase d-none d-lg-inline-block"
              to="/"
            >
              {this.props.brandText}
            </Link>
            <Form className="navbar-search navbar-search-dark form-inline mr-3 d-none d-md-flex ml-lg-auto" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
              <FormGroup className="mb-0">
                <InputGroup className="input-group-alternative">
                  <InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">
                    <InputGroupText>
                      <i className="fas fa-search" />
                    </InputGroupText>
                  </InputGroupAddon>
                  <Input placeholder="Search" type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                </InputGroup>
              </FormGroup>
            </Form>
            <Nav className="align-items-center d-none d-md-flex" navbar>
              <UncontrolledDropdown nav>
                <DropdownToggle className="pr-0" nav>
                  <Media className="align-items-center">
                    <span className="avatar avatar-sm rounded-circle">
                      <img
                        alt="..."
                        src={require("assets/img/theme/team-4-800x800.jpg")}
                      />
                    </span>
                    <Media className="ml-2 d-none d-lg-block">
                      <span className="mb-0 text-sm font-weight-bold">
                        Jessica Jones
                      </span>
                    </Media>
                  </Media>
                </DropdownToggle>
                <DropdownMenu className="dropdown-menu-arrow" right>
                  <DropdownItem className="noti-title" header tag="div">
                    <h6 className="text-overflow m-0">Welcome!</h6>
                  </DropdownItem>
                  <DropdownItem to="/admin/user-profile" tag={Link}>
                    <i className="ni ni-single-02" />
                    <span>My profile</span>
                  </DropdownItem>
                  <DropdownItem to="/admin/user-profile" tag={Link}>
                    <i className="ni ni-settings-gear-65" />
                    <span>Settings</span>
                  </DropdownItem>
                  <DropdownItem to="/admin/user-profile" tag={Link}>
                    <i className="ni ni-calendar-grid-58" />
                    <span>Activity</span>
                  </DropdownItem>
                  <DropdownItem to="/admin/user-profile" tag={Link}>
                    <i className="ni ni-support-16" />
                    <span>Support</span>
                  </DropdownItem>
                  <DropdownItem divider />
                  <DropdownItem href="#pablo" onClick={e => e.preventDefault()}>
                    <i className="ni ni-user-run" />
                    <span>Logout</span>
                  </DropdownItem>
                </DropdownMenu>
              </UncontrolledDropdown>
            </Nav>
          </Container>
        </Navbar>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default AdminNavbar;
```

**Sentiment.js**

```
import React, {useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import AdminNavbar from './Navbars/AdminNavbar';

export default function Sentiment(props) {
    console.log("*****************************************")
    console.log(AdminNavbar.props)
    const [result,setResult] = useState(null);
    const message = async() =>{
        try{
            let res = await axios.get('/sentiment-analysis/AAPL');
            let result = res.data;
            setResult(result);
        }catch(e){
            console.log(e)
        }
    } 

    useEffect(() => {
        message()
    },[])
    return (
        <div>
           {result} 
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: If AdminNavbar and Sentiment are not in a parent-child relationship or don't share the same parent, you can't pass the state between them.

Comment: no they have same parent

Comment: @TiyasaMallick You can with redux or context... it's definitely possible

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using context or redux to pass state around globally.